# Clear the cell content before the keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear the data before the keyword **TRUE** including blank cells in between, and also I don't want to hardcode the range because the range will keep on change. can anyone please help me with this.

```
A
1
2
3
4
5

3
4


53

53

TRUE
```

Comment: Are there a single `True` on the last row of A:A column? Why to `clear` blank cells? Are there formulas returning `""` (nothing)? What do you mean by "hardcode the range" for such a simple task?

Comment: You could do a `Do Until` loop to go down column A clearing/deleting everything until it finds the value `TRUE`? No ranges needed, hardcoded or otherwise :)

Comment: Do you want to clear or delete cells? `...including blank cells` means already clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it is what you need.

```
Option Explicit
Sub clr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 'The sheet where the data are
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A:A") 'Range where the data are
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Set rngFind = rng.Find("TRUE") 'Find TRUE
    Dim rngClear As Range
    Set rngClear = Range("A1", rngFind.Offset(-1)) 'Set the range to clear
    rngClear.Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that cell containing value "True" as the last value in the column "A". If that is the case below code will clear the content of all the cells above to it.

```
Sub ClearCells()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim actSheet As Worksheet

Set actSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With actSheet
    lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & lastRow - 1).Clear
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks,
KV Ramana